# Using pandas to select customers unique to each organization

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
month organization customer_id
01     ABC          001
01     ABC          001
01     ABC          002
02     XYZ          003
03     XYZ          002
06     XYZ          006
04     XYZ          007
03     DEF          004
04     DEF          005
04     MNO          004
```

Using pandas, I would like to group by each organization and distinct count the number of customers unique to each organization (if a customer visited another organization then the customer is not unique).

Desired output

```
organization   unique_customer_count
ABC              1
XYZ              3
DEF              1
```

How can I achieve this using pandas? I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

First remove duplicates per both columns by first [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then remove duplicates per `customer_id` and last count unique values per `organization`:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['organization','customer_id'])
         .drop_duplicates(['customer_id'], keep=False)
         .groupby('organization', sort=False)
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='unique_customer_count'))
print (df1)
  organization  unique_customer_count
0          ABC                      1
1          XYZ                      3
2          DEF                      1
```